# Failed to register the Service Worker: The operation is insecure

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, parceljs, msw

I'm having trouble using [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/docs/) in a React project. The application is bundled using parceljs inside the `dist` folder, the pages are visualized correctly however msw is unable to register the service worker. I followed all the setup suggest in the msw [documentation](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/install) but not matter how my application is run in http or https with self-signed certificates, Firefox 100 will output

```
Failed to get service worker registration(s): Storage access is restricted in this context due to user settings or private browsing mode.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.
```

Or Chrome

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [MSW] Failed to register the Service Worker:

Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:1234/') with script ('https://localhost:1234/mockServiceWorker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
    at index.js:684:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (RequestHandler-deps.js:36:47)
```

Despite following the troubleshooting guidelines [here](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/using-local-https).

The only way to have msw running is to open the application using the anonymous mode in Firefox but in the console the service workers are registered in fallback mode

```
[MSW] Mocking enabled (fallback mode).
```

My system is Ubuntu 22.04, nodejs version 16.14, parceljs version 2.5.0, msw version 0.38.1.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, your SSL certificate is not trusted by your browser.

There's a designated [Using local HTTPS](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/using-local-https) recipe in MSW documentation, I highly recommend you read it. It lists all the possible ways to resolve this issue.

> Context: you cannot register a Service Worker in an insecure environment. Such environments include HTTP or self-signed (untrusted) HTTPS. I believe the latter is precisely your case.

I'd recommend whitelisting `localhost`, making the browser treat it as secure. In Chrome, you can do that by:

1. Opening `chrome://flags`.
2. Finding the `allow-insecure-localhost` flag and enabling it.

Alternatively, consider serving your app locally with an actual certificate that the browser may verify. Browsers often provide you with feedback around the certificate validity, mentioning exact things that fail.

Also, if you're running Firefox in a private mode, I think they [don't support Service Workers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1320796) in that scenario. Switch from the private mode back to the regular mode, and the worker should register.